# Js templating content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, symfony

I'm working on a social network, i decided to return ajax responses in Json instead of html, then use Handlebars.js or any templating system to convert it into html, but the problem is the following:
I'm working with Symfony Framework, so I check if the request is XHR then i return a JsonResponse, but what I'm supposed to do for js templates translation, when the response is not XHR, i render a php/Twig response using translation component, but what about js templates? 
An exemple:

```html
<h1> Product Title: {{product.title}} </h1>
<a href="/edit-{{product.id}}">
    Edit Product
</a>

<h1> Titre de produit: {{product.title}} </h1>
<a href="/edit-{{product.id}}">
    Editer le produit
</a>
```

I guess i shouldn't create 100x js templtes for differents languages, it will be unmaintainable. What does sites like Twitter do to manipulate their Json responses? Do they send translations with Json content?

I apologize for my bad english, I'm french.. Thank you!

Comment: Give a JSON with the content of each language. It's an example [here](https://gist.github.com/jsgao0/8d34ffcf2f793b7fe36c0fb295511155).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want translation only you could use from [JsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle)
.

and you will be able to use translation form javascript,or
you can add convert the translation file to json object and send it with the response.

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$translationArray = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/tranlation/file.yml'));

// $resopnse is the array you convert it to JsonResopnse;

$response['translation'] = $translationArray;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I knew this bundle but it loads the whole translations, I guess the second one is good, but from a performance side, it's okay? Or it will be better to load & send html directly instead of Json & parsing Yml translation file?

Comment: if you use the same template for rendering the data and update it .
you could send the template first then update it with the data

Comment: I don't undrestand, can you clarify please?

Comment: I will choose the second method and decouple translations files for specific controllers so it will contain just the needed translations..  Response accepted. Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome,  what i meant : when you request the link, send the [template as response and cache it]  (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html)  then  send the data via ajax to update the template with data.  This is my approach but with angularjs

Comment: :o Interesting, I have just 2 question if possible: 
1- There is a way to pre-compile these templates server-side before caching them?
2 - For forms, i guess I should copy the view of the form and past it in the JS(static) template and change just the CRSF value (sended with Json data), or there is an other way to do that?
Thank's again

Comment: if you want to pass dynamic data to the twig template you cant cache it . you need to use controller.
I didn't understand what you mean about copy form view.. but you can send form data via ajax request as **json** eg, `{"formName":{"filed1":"value1", "filed2":"value2" , "_token":"CSRF token"}}`

Comment: Not form data, What I mean, how can I generate the form view in the template, I guess it's not possible to pass the entire formView in Json via controller, so I think I should generate the view and then manually past it in the template, 
<form......>
<input....>
The only data I must send is the CSRF token, so I will generate it in the controller.

Comment: yes i generate my forms manually . also its better for styling forms